# I have to compare pre and post training effectiveness for group of Managers statistically

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have to compare pre and post training effectiveness for group of Managers who have undergone training programme. I have data based on rank order from 1 to 4 where 1 being the most preferred and 4 being the least preferred . Based on the pre and post data i have to give the percentage improvement in the mangers . Which statistical method should be used for measuring effectiveness of managers.

Comment: Can you expand on this? At the moment it is unclear what your dataset is and the exact question you want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just checking only if there are differences between the same group such as before test and after test to see if there are improvements you can use ANOVA.

If you are looking at how much improvement from the test I would use t-test.

This source may interest you for looking at which test to use: http://www.csun.edu/~amarenco/Fcs%20682/When%20to%20use%20what%20test.pdf